# Is there any way to use variable name inside pandas apply function

Tags: python, pandas

how to use variable name inside pandas apply function . Need to pass function name dynamically to apply function.

```
func_name='int'
df['column3'] = df['column3'].apply(func_name)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)

Comment: What is the purpose of doing that? Let us know your end goal, there might be better alternatives. You can access the variable name within a *lambda* function. If you want to pass arguments use *args* parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is globals() :

```
x = 3
def func(x):
    return x**2
var = 'func'
print(globals()[var](x))
```

This code will print 9.